# Error when accessing httpClient data response properties

Tags: angular, typescript

In my server i got this dto like this :

```
public class PreNewProjetDTO {
    public List<BasicItemDTO> etatsProj;
}

public class BasicItemDTO {
    public Integer id;
    public String label;
}
```

But when i try this ajax call with `angular 5`

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.http.get('/api/new-projet').subscribe(data => {

      console.log(data);

      for (let ep in data.etatsProj) {
        console.log(ep.label); 
      }

    });
  }
```

I got the json

```
{
 "etatsProj":
    [
       {"id":1,"label":"programmé"},
       {"id":2,"label":"en cours"},
       {"id":3,"label":"achevé"},
       {"id":4,"label":"annulé"}
    ]
}
```

I got this error

```
ERROR in src/app/new-projet/new-projet.component.ts(23,27): error TS2339: Property 'etatsProj' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src/app/new-projet/new-projet.component.ts(24,24): error TS2339: Property 'label' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Comment: Could you post the json received from /api/new-projet in the description of the question?

Comment: @jeprubio done.

Comment: Maybe it is a typing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First option**

You can try to define a variable of type `any` and assign to it your data fetched from the server.

```
 this.http.get('/api/new-projet').subscribe(data => {

   console.log(data);
   let newData: any = data;
   for (let ep of newData.etatsProj) {
    console.log(ep.label); 
   }

});
```

Or another way of doing the same thing:

```
this.http.get<any>('/api/new-projet').subscribe(data => {

   for (let ep of data.etatsProj) {
    console.log(ep.label); 
   }

});
```

*This option is not recommended since we loose the type of variable we are processing*.

**Second option**

With the new `HttpClient`, there is no need to parse the JSON response. However, from the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) we have to do this: :

> The responseType value determines how a successful response body will be parsed. If responseType is the default json, a type interface for the resulting object may be passed as a type parameter to request().

So you can define new interfaces in the same component or add them to a `global.d.ts` file for the typings.

```
Interface PreNewProjetDTO {
    let etatsProj: BasicItemDTO[];
}

Interface BasicItemDTO {
    let id: number;
    let label: string;
}
```

And you will rewrite you `get` function this way:

```
 this.http.get<PreNewProjetDTO>('/api/new-projet').subscribe(data => {

   for (let ep of data.etatsProj) {
    console.log(ep.label); 
   }

});
```

Comment: i still got `ERROR in src/app/new-projet/new-projet.component.ts(25,24): error TS2339: Property 'label' does not exist on type 'string'.`

Comment: first option => i got `undefined` values

Comment: I don't want to use Second option to keep it simple like in vanilla js

Comment: you can add a 3rd option `this.http.get<any>('/api/new-projet')..` by just adding <any> it works like i want. But also i change to `of` instead of `in` in for loop.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is no need to use it. We were having the issue of property `label` not defined before because of the `in` instead of `of`.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to map the response into json first like

> .map(result => result.json())

and then you can use the cast the json to data type

```
this.http.get('/api/new-projet')
    .map(result => result.json());
    .subscribe((data: PreNewProjetDTO) => {

      console.log(data);

      for (let ep in data.etatsProj) {
        console.log(ep.label); 
      }

    });
```

Comment: The data return by get in the new version of angular is already parsed into JSON.

Comment: @edkeveked thanks, i did not know that. On the other hand Youssef did not provide actual angular version used.

Comment: You're welcome. You can have a look at the documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)